# Will one become a kafir because of his minor shirk?

Tags: shirk

Will one become a kafir because of his minor shirk and permanently reside in the hellfire?

Comment: If someone who did minor shirk and became kafir then why is it called minor shirk? Isn't it major shirk then?

Answer (score 1):

**No, not necessarily!**

Minor shirk, like doing any action with an intention other than exclusively for Allah, can be very difficult for most people to avoid. It can be subtle, hidden, accidental, or fleeting. Even many people who believe in Allah are guilty of it:

> وَما يُؤمِنُ أَكثَرُهُم بِاللَّهِ إِلّا وَهُم مُشرِكونَ
>
> And most of them do not believe in Allah without ascribing partners to Him. [Yusuf, 12:106]

It does not imply kufr! And it certainly does not guarantee eternal punishment.

If you catch yourself committing shirk (minor or major), perhaps while in a state of heedlessness, correct your intentions/behaviour and seek forgiveness.

> إِنَّ الَّذينَ اتَّقَوا إِذا مَسَّهُم طائِفٌ مِنَ الشَّيطانِ تَذَكَّروا فَإِذا هُم مُبصِرونَ
>
> When those who are Godwary are touched by a visitation of Satan, they remember [Allah] and, behold, they perceive. [al-A'raaf, 7:201]

Allah can forgive any sin, including shirk (even the major kind!), if the person repents from it.

> قُل يا عِبادِيَ الَّذينَ أَسرَفوا عَلىٰ أَنفُسِهِم لا تَقنَطوا مِن رَحمَةِ اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغفِرُ الذُّنوبَ جَميعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الغَفورُ الرَّحيمُ
>
> Say [that Allah declares,] ‘O My servants who have committed excesses against their own souls, do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed Allah will forgive all sins. Indeed He is the All-forgiving, the All-merciful. [al-Zumar, 39:53]

Also, be grateful to Allah for making you aware of your flaws and giving you a chance to correct them while you still have a chance.